# Working the check box laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, checkbox, laravel-5

I am having problem working my check box basically am trying to save in a diff location if checkbox is true don't know what am doing wrong here is my code.Error displays

> FatalErrorException in PostController.php line 64:syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

thanks in advance.

**creat.blade**`

```
<div>
    {{ Form::label('check_box', "Check Box") }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('check_box', 'true') }}
</div>
```

**Postcontroller**`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;
use App\Tag;
use App\Category;
use Session;

use Image;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        return view('posts.create')->withCategories($categories)->withTags($tags);
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // validate the data
        $this->validate($request, array(
                'title'         => 'required|max:255',
                'slug'          => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
                'category_id'   => 'required|integer',
                'body'          => 'required'
            ));
        // store in the database
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $checkbox = Input::get('check_box');

        $post->$checkbox

        if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {

          $image = $request->file('featured_image');
          $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            if (Input::get('check_box') === 'true') {
                $post->checkbox = 'true';  // UPDATE:must be true of course
                $location = public_path('images/profile' . $filename);
              Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('800', '400')->save($location);

            $post->image = $filename;

            } else {
                $post->checkbox = 'false'; // UPDATE:must be false of course
                $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
              Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('800', '400')->save($location);


          $post->image = $filename; }

        }

        $post->save();
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
        Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully save!');
        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.show')->withPost($post);
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        // find the post in the database and save as a var
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $categories = Category::all();
        $cats = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cats[$category->id] = $category->name;
        }
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $tags2 = array();
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->name;
        }
        // return the view and pass in the var we previously created
        return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($cats)->withTags($tags2);
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Validate the data
        $post = Post::find($id);
        if ($request->input('slug') == $post->slug) {
            $this->validate($request, array(
                'title' => 'required|max:255',
                'category_id' => 'required|integer',
                'body'  => 'required'
            ));
        } else {
        $this->validate($request, array(
                'title' => 'required|max:255',
                'slug'  => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
                'category_id' => 'required|integer',
                'body'  => 'required'
            ));
        }
        // Save the data to the database
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
        $post->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
        $post->body = Purifier::clean($request->input('body'));
        $post->save();
        if (isset($request->tags)) {
            $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        } else {
            $post->tags()->sync(array());
        }
        // set flash data with success message
        Session::flash('success', 'This post was successfully saved.');
        // redirect with flash data to posts.show
        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->tags()->detach();
        $post->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'The post was successfully deleted.');
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: A closing bracket for your `else` may be missing.

Comment: that didn't work @graybeard

Comment: `that didn't work` is too little to help. I don't get to see 64 lines from your _PostController.php_, the last closing bracket is tacked to the end of a line and seems to belong to `function show($id)` - I can't see one corresponding to `class PostController` before the closing `?>`. (Who's graybeard - a brother from another mother, unbeknownst to me?)

Comment: sorry  about that it's been edited  you get the 64th line around the first  if statement now.Thanks again.

Comment: Very disappointing it didn't start working to show appreciation for commenting the code. But, then, line 62 seems to be missing a `;`.

Comment: Thanks i have added the missing ; and i now i get " TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php " error on a different file.trying sort to sort now .i appreciate.